Reissner-Nordström black holes and naked singularities
I often read that there is no known mechanism that prevents a charged black hole, if the charge is high enough compared to its irreducible mass, from forming a naked singularity. But I don't get how that is possible.
Imagine a hollow sphere of charge $q$, with an “infinite” radius and “infinitesimal” mass. Imagine we start shrinking it. To do that we need to do work. That work will create mass, which will be added to the mass our sphere.
If we keep shrinking and shrinking, at some point we will reach a radius equal to
$$r = \sqrt{\frac{G q^2}{8 \pi \epsilon_0 c^4}}$$
At that point, the mass that we will have piled up through our shrinking will be equal to
$$m = \sqrt{\frac{q^2}{8 \pi \epsilon_0 G}}$$
Is that not a black hole with an event horizon (at half of its Schwarzschild radius, due to how Reissner-Nordström metric works)? What should I do to create a naked singularity?
EDIT: Maybe my question is not clear enough, so I will try to formulate it better: In which way one could, theoretically, create a naked singularity – or, to put it differently, a black hole “with more charge than mass”? I can't find a way; so to me naked singularities seem mathematically impossible even just theoretically speaking.

“I often read that there is no known mechanism that prevents a charged black hole [...] from forming a naked singularity” - Don’t believe everything you read +1.

Where have you even read that, in all the references I know they say it is impossible to overcharge a black hole since additional same signed charges will get repelled when the black hole's charge is already at the limit.

@safesphere Good point in general.

@Yukterez: The fact that additional charge gets repelled is not the reason; you can always force it to cross the event horizon by brute force (e.g. by shooting it towards the black hole with a cannon). The reason however is that your brute force will do work, and that work will be added to the final mass of the black hole. Therefore the more charge you add the more mass you add too. So for me it is impossible to overcharge a black hole indeed.

@Yukterez The gravitational attraction diverges at the horizon. For a charge to be repelled, the electrostatic repulsion also must diverge at the horizon. Can you confirm that it does?

@safesphere - see here for the d²r/dτ² at the horizon with different initial velocities. Moonblink is right though, if you still force the charged particle in the kinetic energy you need for that equals more mass equivalent than the charge you add, in that case you would add more mass than charge to the black hole.

@Yukterez Yes, his reasoning seems correct, that’s why I’ve upvoted.

The Schwarzschild metric is
$$c^2\mathrm{d}\tau^2=k_Sc^2 \mathrm{d} t^2-k_S^{-1} \mathrm{d} r^2-\mathrm{d} \Omega^2$$
for the metric on a sphere $\mathrm{d}\Omega$ and the “Schwarzschild factor” $k_S=1-\frac{r_s}{r}=1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}$. There is obviously a horizon at $r=r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$, where the escape velocity is equal to lightspeed, and where the Schwarzschild factor vanishes. Inside this horizon the signs of the timelike and spacelike terms switch (not good for anyone trying to get inside). The Reissner-Nordstrom metric is nearly identical:
$$c^2\mathrm{d}\tau^2=k_{RN}c^2 \mathrm{d} t^2-k_{RN}^{-1} \mathrm{d} r^2-\mathrm{d} \Omega^2$$
where $k_{RN}=1-\frac{r_s}{r}+\frac{r_Q^2}{r^2}=1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}+\frac{Q^2G}{4\pi\epsilon_0c^4r^2}$. Evidently, for $Q\ll M$, there is still a horizon, but there is also an interior horizon within which the sign of the time and radial terms in the metric are still normal. Increasing $Q$ makes the radius of this interior horizon increase. Specifically, there are two horizons with radii given by
$$r=\frac{1}{2}\left(r_s\pm\sqrt{r_s^2-4r_Q^2}\right).$$
If the interior horizon’s radius is greater than or equal to the radius of the exterior horizon, then there ends up being no event horizon: the “normal” space inside the black hole has been expanded past the event horizon which produces causal connections between points at infinity and the worldline at $r=0$, which is a naked singularity. This also corresponds to the value under the square root up there being negative since event horizons of imaginary radius correspond, physically, to no event horizons.
The reason this happens is because of the sign of the charge term in the Reissner-Nordstrom factor. Unlike the mass term, it is positive, so for large enough $Q$, that term can be made to never actually reach zero, and thus not ever producing a horizon (in this particular case).
To identify one such superextremal naked-singularity case, simply find a $Q$ large enough. Given the above relationship the event horizons coincide for $r_s=2r_Q$ and disappear for $r_s<2r_Q$; that should be easy enough to figure out from there.

In other words, qualitatively: the charge of the black hole reduces the (exterior) event horizon radius because of how it interacts with spacetime. Under the proper RN metric, increasing $Q$ makes the event horizon shrink and eventually produces a naked singularity for a finite $Q$ and $M$.
In the case of the RN metric, you can't have a superextremal black hole (same with Kerr and KN as far as I know), because adding more charge to a sub-extremal black hole requires doing work which increases the black hole's mass correspondingly so that you can't ever reach extremum. The cosmic censorship hypothesis states that this is generally true, i.e. that no black hole metric can be made to form a naked singularity, but it has not yet been proven.

I think the question is not about how to interpret the metric but about what physical process can go from no black hole at the start to a naked singularity case at the end, because it is hard to see how the mass of a charged hole can end up small enough to realize that condition.

My point here is primarily that any RN black hole with such-and-such inequalities is a naked singularity. To my knowledge, it doesn’t matter how you get there; the black hole with $m$ described in the post would be extremal in the sense that if you added any more charge it would lose its event horizon.

@controlgroup Thank you for the review of Reissner-Nordström metric. However I was more asking in which way, theoretically, one could obtain a naked singularity – because I can't seem to find a way. From my calculations you cannot convert a sub-extremal black hole to a naked singularity (a.k.a. super-extremal black hole) only by adding further charge, because adding further charge will require work, and that work will increase the mass as well (so the mass will always keep up, no matter how much charge you add).

In the case of the RN metric, you can't have a superextremal black hole (same with Kerr and KN as far as I know), for precisely the reason you describe. The cosmic censorship hypothesis states that this is generally true, i.e. that no black hole metric can be made to form a naked singularity, but it has not yet been proven.

@controlgroup Thank you. I think your last comment pretty much answers my question. If you edit your answer and incorporate what you just wrote, I will be happy to accept your answer as the solution :-)

I don't think it does answer the question. Sure. if the CCH is true then you can't have naked singularities, but in your OP you're asking about whether we can feed a black hole charge until it becomes super-extremal (or start with charges on a shell that becomes superextremal as it collapses). Even without CCH that might not be possible, if the work required to push that charge together enlarges the hole enough to keep it on the happy side of extremal. A real answer should show that calculation. Also, this answer seems very AI assisted.

@HarryWilson The current answer is indeed didascalic and not so much on topic with my specific question (which is how to create naked singularities in general, not just by “feeding charge” – that was only the first approach that came to my mind – I was actually looking for alternatives). However the comment that controlgroup added later does answer the question: naked singularities are mathematically impossible in the known metrics (so no approach whatsoever would work).

@HarryWilson Believe it or not, I wrote this answer myself. The $k_S$ and $k_{RN}$ terminology is actually not very standard (I use it myself because those factors come up a lot in my work) so it shouldn't be expected to come up in a low-quality AI-generated response.

Sorry, it was clear to me that your answer wasn't all AI, but often you will see AI answers that make lots of salient points that nevertheless fail to actually address the question at hand, and that is the feeling I got from this answer. It reminds me of a time someone asked for a topological space that doesn't have the homotopy type of a CW-complex, and, though my answer was correct, when asked for a proof I spurted facts related to the question, but not actually proving my claim.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523416/is-there-any-example-of-space-not-having-the-homotopy-type-of-a-cw-complex/523446#523446
